# Get the right encoding from header (java/dropwizard)

Tags: java, rest, character-encoding, http-headers, dropwizard

I'm trying to get the right charset from the header request. but unfortunatly i always get a default charset=UTF-8, what ever I send in the header i always get the same. 
Here is for example my code:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
public Object customers(@NotNull InputStream requestStream, 
@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
String  contentTypeHeader = headers.getRequestHeader("Content-Type") != null 
? headers.getRequestHeader("Content-Type").get(0) : null;
return null;
}
```

Example : 
[image]

I'm asking for your help.
Thanks

Comment: Please share some examples of how you are sending the header in the request. Thanks.

Comment: @AndréBarbosa I have added an example

Comment: Just tested this exact sample of code on a local DW app and I can see the expected header: contentTypeHeader = "text/xml;charset=UTF-32". Which version of DW is being using? Is there a @Consumes defined in the class?

Comment: I didn't defined a @Consume in the class because I don't know exactly what I get from the header,
Dropwizard version : 1.1.0.
I have tested it localy and I get contentTypeHeader = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8".

Comment: @AndréBarbosa i have write my response in the last comment

Comment: I have tested with the same version and without @Consume and I am still able to retrieve the correct charset from the header. Is there some kind of layer on top of the DW application like apache, nginx, etc?

Comment: @AndréBarbosa  I have used Postman to test with, unfortunatly when i set the body as a raw the charset wil be set autonatically to "UTF-8", that's why the Content-Type in the header will not be considered.
Thx for your help

Comment: I have also used Postman for the tests and it worked for me. Have you tried using a curl command? curl -d '<a></a>' -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-32" http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: no I have used Insomnia for test instead of Postman.

Comment: And you were able to retrieve the correct charset with Insomnia?

Comment: @AndréBarbosa  yes :)